# Weird data type error using tensorflow and numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I don't understand the difference betwen the two codes here below:

Is there a reason why this works:

```
def evaluer_dessin ():
    global result,img
    listeimage=[]
    for y in matrice:
        for x in y:
            listeimage.append(x)
    img = np.array([listeimage])

    afficher_resultat()  

    try:
        Cadre.delete(result)
    except:
        pass
    if evaluerimg:
        result=Cadre.create_text(Largeur/2,Hauteur/8,text="c'est un 
"+str((prediction[0]+1)%10),font=('', '50'),fill="red")
    root.after(300,evaluer_dessin)

def afficher_resultat():
    global prediction
    prediction = session.run(y_pred_cls,feed_dict={ x : img})
```

But this code here doesn't :

```
def evaluer_dessin ():
    global result
    listeimage=[]
    for y in matrice:
        for x in y:
            listeimage.append(x)
    img = np.array([listeimage])

    # this is the line that doesn't work, it says that it cant convert an
    # int into a tensor
    prediction = session.run(y_pred_cls,feed_dict={ x : img})

    try:
        Cadre.delete(result)
    except:
        pass
    if evaluerimg:
        result=Cadre.create_text(Largeur/2,Hauteur/8,text="c'est un 
"+str((prediction[0]+1)%10),font=('', '50'),fill="red")
    root.after(300,evaluer_dessin)
```

It says that "img" is an int but it's type is clearly an array, and the weirdest thing is that when I use a seperate function to calculate the prediction, it works well!

Here's the error shown for the second program:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1092, in _run
>    subfeed, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
>    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3579, in >_as_graph_element_locked
>    types_str))
>TypeError: Can not convert a int into a Tensor.
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\CNN_exe\programmeCNNexe.py", line 170, in <module>
>    evaluer_dessin()
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\CNN_exe\programmeCNNexe.py", line 123, in >evaluer_dessin
>    prediction = session.run(y_pred_cls,feed_dict={ x : img})
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
>    run_metadata_ptr)
>  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1095, in _run
>    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
>TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into >a Tensor.
>[Finished in 2.1s with exit code 1]
>[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\CNN_exe\programmeCNNexe.py"]
>[dir: C:\Users\nicol\Desktop\CNN_exe]
>[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS >Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Syst>em32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management >Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine >Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData>\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\>Python\Python35\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\>;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\nicol\AppData\>Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Comment: Interesting question - would you mind including the full error message (including a stacktrace if you get any) into the question? (just press "edit" and you can add it)

Comment: The problem is not with `img`, but with `x`. In `afficher_resultat` seems to be a global variable, and in `evaluer_dessin` it comes from the global variable `matrice` (from the loop), so it is hard to tell when or why it should work or not, but in any case it seems it is not a tensor from the graph, but a plain integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks jdehesa for helping me solving the problem. The problem came actually from the variable x and not form img.
All I had to do was to give another name to the the variable in the for loop:

```
def evaluer_dessin ():
    global listeimage,result,img
    listeimage=[]
    for y in matrice:
        for z in y: # I just change the name from "x" to "z" and the problem was solved
            listeimage.append(z)
    img = np.array([listeimage])

    prediction = session.run(y_pred_cls,feed_dict={ x : img})

    try:
        Cadre.delete(result)
    except:
        pass
    if evaluerimg:
        result=Cadre.create_text(Largeur/2,Hauteur/8,text="c'est un "+str((prediction[0]+1)%10),font=('', '50'),fill="red")
    root.after(300,evaluer_dessin)
```

I'm new to stackoverflow and I just wanted to say how awesome this website is, you get all the answers you want by clever and nice people.